# How to make sequelize.sync() omit some models?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I use tables and views in my DB (mysql), so for dev/test environment I want to use sync(), but it crashes on views.

Can I somehow omit these models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did :

```
const MyView = sequelize.define('myView', {
  ids: {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.INTEGER)
  },
  volumeSum: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }
});

// To avoid table creation
MyView.sync = () => Promise.resolve();
```

Then `sequelize.sync();` didn't create the table for the view.
I hope, it helps...

Comment: Great tip, thanks! The benefit of this approach is that you can still rely on Sequelize to manage the order of syncing your models correctly, with respect to **foreign keys**. If you try to manually call `model.sync()` on each of your models as @gary-johnson suggested, you are responsible for ensuring they are ordered correctly.

Answer (score 10):

I use a method quite similar to Crusader's answer when I want to create and use Views with Sequelize. In this case I do not want to have Sequelize try and sync the view as it results in a table being created. To do this I add the following to a Sequelize model:

```
var MyView = sequelize.define("MyView", {
  status: { type: DataTypes.TEXT },
},
{
  doNotSync: true,
  tableName: "myDatabaseView", // The actual view name in database
  classMethods: {
    createView: function(models) {
      return sequelize.query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myDatabaseView ...;");
    }
});
```

Now I have that setup I need to make sure the views are not included when I create the database and that the `createView` method is called on each of the views.

```
var tables = [];
sequelize.modelManager.forEachModel(m => {
    if (m.options.doNotSync !== true) {
      tables.push(m);
    }              
});

return Sequelize.Promise.each(tables, t => {

  return t.sync({force: true});

}).then(_ => {

  var views = [];
  sequelize.modelManager.forEachModel(m => {
      if (m.options.doNotSync && m.createView) {
        views.push(m);
      }              
  });

  return Sequelize.Promise.each(views, v => {

    return v.createView(sequelize.models);

  });

});
```

Also, just to be on the safe side I add hooks to prevent using any of the create/update/delete operations on the views.

```
hooks: {
  beforeBulkCreate: throwNotAllowedError,
  beforeBulkDestroy: throwNotAllowedError,
  beforeBulkUpdate: throwNotAllowedError,
  beforeCreate: throwNotAllowedError,
  beforeDestroy: throwNotAllowedError,
  beforeUpdate: throwNotAllowedError
}
```

Where `throwNotAllowedError` is a simple function

```
function throwNotAllowedError() {
  throw new Error("Operation not allowed on a view");
}
```

Hope that helps. Getting views into Sequelize has given us a massive increate in productivity on the project.

And you can still create relationships and associations from the views allowing you to use the `include:[]` notation to bring additional tables into your view query.

Comment: Thorough answer. This should be part of the official sequelize documentation. It is very good. Thank you for this. Now we can use views with sequelize as well.

Comment: When using sequelize-typescript it gives an error saying doNotSync does not exist and it also doesnt detect Sequelize.Promise

Answer (score 2):

You cannot skip models by using sync on main sequelize,

but instead you can use model sync function and only call sync function on models you want sync

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#sync-promisethis

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as told Keval I need to sync() on models, so I copy/paste code from sequelize.sync() and change it:

```
if (config.sync && config.sync != 'false') {
  let models = [];
  sequelize.modelManager.forEachModel(function(model) {
    if (model && model.options.sync !== false) {
      models.push(model);
    } else {
      // DB should throw an SQL error if referencing inexistant table
    }
  });
  return Sequelize.Promise.each(models, function(model) {
    return model.sync(config.sync);
  });
}
```