# Unable to create views in mysql using sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Currently, I am building a web app with nodejs + mysql and sequelize as ORM. I want to create some views like we do in mysql, but I can't find any option in **Sequelize** to create views.

Is there any ORM where it's possible to create views? Or is it possible to do it with sequelize?

Comment: There is a beautiful way of handling views on Sequelize in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42795937/2730233

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are no builtin methods for managing views in Sequelize, but you can create them using plain SQL queries and manage them with normal Sequelize models.

If you're using [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) for your migrations as recommended by the Sequelize docs, you can create your view using a migration similar to this:

```
const view_name = 'my_view';
const query = '<SQL QUERY THAT RETURNS YOUR VIEW>';
module.exports = {
  up: function (database, Sequelize) {
    return database.query(`CREATE VIEW ${view_name} AS ${query}`);
  },
  down: function (database, Sequelize) {
    return database.query(`DROP VIEW ${view_name}`);
  }
}
```

For view changes or updates, you should use the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW syntax to ensure you can roll back your schema changes - avoid the tempation to DROP the old view and CREATE a new one!

```
const view_name = 'my_view';
const original_query = '<SQL QUERY THAT RETURNS YOUR VIEW>';
const new_query = '<SQL QUERY THAT RETURNS YOUR UPDATED VIEW>';
module.exports = {
  up: function (database, Sequelize) {
    return database.query(`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ${view_name} AS ${new_query}`);
  },
  down: function (database, Sequelize) {
    return database.query(`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ${view_name} AS ${original_query}`);
  }
}
```

The exact code snippets will, of course, vary depending on how you've been setting up migrations so far.

Once your migration is all set, create a Sequelize model representing your view schema as usual, using the view name as your table name. All of the `find` family functions should work as expected, while `update`, `delete`, and `create` should be expected to fail.

You can reference the Sequelize docs for [raw queries](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html), and this [example repo](https://github.com/abelnation/sequelize-migration-hello) for using Umzug with Sequelize. The only formal documentation I can find for Umzug itself is on its [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/umzug).

Comment: Great answer! For anyone else that generates their migrations with sequelize-cli, you'll notice the `database` parameter in the up/down functions shows up as a `queryInterface` - you can't just use `queryInterface.query` as it's not valid - to get the object to run a raw query on, you need: `queryInterface.sequelize.query`.

Comment: ERROR: database.query is not a function "sequelize": "^6.6.5",